# How to focus among the search results on draft-js editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I've implemented the find and replace feature like this tutorial and it works neat: https://reactrocket.com/post/draft-js-search-and-replace/

I want to know how it will be to have some focus() on the editor's search result every time user hits enter on the search box, looping among the results, similar to native google chrome's find feature.

Comment: Pseudo code: `searchBox.onKeyPress(enter) -> result.next.color(yellow).scrollToView()` simplified, but this might help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest the following solution to the issue. Working demo - https://jsfiddle.net/levsha/o3xyvkw7/ For a start, we define `activeHighlightIndex` property in the component state. We will be store index of active highlighting here.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    search: '',
    replace: '',
    activeHighlightIndex: 0,
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText(string)),
  }
}
```

Bind `onKeyDown` handler on search input. If it's `enter` button, we increase `activeHighlightIndex`.

```
onKeyDown = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) { // enter
    this.setState({
      activeHighlightIndex: this.state.activeHighlightIndex + 1
    });
  }
}
```

In `componentDidUpdate` method we apply appropriate styles for the active highlighting element and check if we should scroll the window for the element will be in the viewport.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.search.length) {
    const allHighlights = this.editor.refs.editor
      .getElementsByClassName('search-and-replace-highlight');
    const index = this.state.activeHighlightIndex % allHighlights.length;
    const newActiveHighlight = allHighlights[index];
    const currentActiveHighlight = this.editor.refs.editor
      .querySelector('.search-and-replace-highlight.active-highlight');

    if (newActiveHighlight && currentActiveHighlight !== newActiveHighlight) {
      currentActiveHighlight && currentActiveHighlight.classList
        .remove('active-highlight');

      newActiveHighlight.classList.add('active-highlight');
      scrollToElementIfNeeded(newActiveHighlight);
    }
  }
}
```